# phpunit testcase for file upload

Tags: php, phpunit, yii

Can anybody help me. How to write file upload phpunit testcase? 
I done it for insert, unique data insertion, delete etc functionality.
Following are my code but its not working properly

```
class FileuploadTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    public $testFile = array(
       'name'=>'2012-04-20 21.13.42.jpg',
       'tmp_name'=>'C:\wamp\tmp\php8D20.tmp',
       'type'=>'image/jpeg',
       'size'=>1472190,
       'error'=>0
    );


public function testFileupload()
    {   

        $testUpload = new Fileupload;
        $testUpload->image = new CUploadedFile($this->testFile['name'],$this->testFile['tmp_name'],$this->testFile['type'],$this->testFile['size'],$this->testFile['error']);
        $this->assertFalse($testUpload->validate());

        $errors= $testUpload->errors;
        $this->assertEmpty($errors);
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem is the temp name part of the array. :facepalm:

Comment: Im getting following error:
FileuploadTest::testFileupload
Failed accerting that true is false....

and displaying error on this line = $this->assertFalse($testUpload->validate());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments, that's what testing is, the `$testUpload->validate()` is returning true, and you are trying to `assert` if it is false, obviously the test will fail.

If `$this->assertFalse($testUpload->validate());` is failing, it means that `$testUpload` is correctly initialized, and hence validation returns true.

To move on to the next assertion in your test you need to use

```
$this->assertTrue($testUpload->validate());
```

You need to read more about unit testing. There are lots of articles on the web, that a simple search will return.

Comment: ask for clarifications if needed

Comment: you are welcome, and do consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). check that link to know how accepting helps everyone. it'll give you and me reputation points, and also help future visitors know that the question is answered.

Comment: yes Mr. BOOL i have accepted your answer. sorry for late reply :) thanx again